# Why does System.out.println(-1<<32)=-1 in Java?

Tags: java

Why does `System.out.println(-1<<32)` display `-1` in Java? Is there any root cause? I hope somebody can explain!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java (and JavaScript), `a << b` automatically wraps `b` modulo the bit length of the numeric type. You're doing it with an `int`, which is 32 bits, and 32 % 32 = 0, therefore, no change. You can always just check for a `b` of more than (bit length - 1) and automatically set to zero instead of shifting.

Comment: So it cannot be used with `long`?

Comment: It works if you use a long literal. `-1L<<32` is equal to `-4294967296`.

Comment: @jonmorgan: Okay... but a long literal is still a `long`. It's not different from a `long` variable in this situation, which is what I took Thilo to mean.

Comment: Yeah, I was just phrasing it in the terms of the original question.